# Proper memory freeing of vector of Base class pointers, which is a member of a derived class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, memory-management, memory-leaks

Let's say I have the following classes:

`Base.hpp`:

```cpp
class Derived;
class Base {
protected:
    Derived *boss;
    //other things
public:
    Base(); constuctor with irrellevant parameters
    virtual ~Base(); // after confirmation from the comments, 
    //I made the destructor virtual but I still experience crashes due to segmentation fault
    // other things
};
```

`Base.cpp`:

```cpp
Base::Base() {}//irrelevant
Base::~Base() {
    delete this->boss; // I am afraid there might be a bug here
    // the Derived class also has this member which points to the instace of the object itself, 
    //therefore, when calling the destructor, I am deleting the object itself, instead of just its member
}
```

`Derived.hpp`:

```cpp
class Derived : public Base {
private:
    std::vector<Base *> employees;
    // other things
public:
    Derived();
    ~Derived();
    // I'd like to make this method add the object to the employees vector without making a copy
    void addEmployee(Base *employee, double salary);
    // I'd like to make this method remove the object from the vector without destroying it, so that it could be given another boss in the future
    void removeEmployee(const std::string &name);
};
```

`Derived.cpp`:

```cpp
Derived::Derived(const std::string &name, const double salary) : Base(name) {
    this->boss = this; //required by my assignment to be that way
    this->salary = salary;
}
Derived::~Derived() {
    for (auto employee:this->employees) {
        // if I don't delete the pointers, there will be a memory leak
        // but If I delete them, I will also be destroying the employees Base class instances
        // this->removeEmployee(this->employees->getName()); doesn't solve my problem either
        delete employee;
    }
    this->team.clear();
}
void Derived::addEmployee(Base *employee, const double salary) {
    if (employee != nullptr) {
        employee->setBoss(this); // a method which sets 'Derived* boss' member of Base class to this Derived instance
        this->team.push_back(developer); //add the object to the vector of employees
        this->team.back()->setSalary(salary);
    }
}

void Derived::removeEmployee(const std::string &name) {
    for (int i = this->employees.size() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        // check for the first name match in reversed order of addition
        if (this->employees[i]->getName() == name) { 
            // set the boss member of the Base instance to nullptr, i.e the Base no longer has a boss
            this->employees[i]->setBoss(nullptr);
            // if I don't delete the pointer, the program experiences even more crashes
            // but that way I also delete the Base class instance, which I want to "live"
            delete this->employees[i];
            // remove the pointer from the vector
            this->employees.erase(this->team.begin() + i);
            // since a match has been found an the employee has been removed, no need to keep on searching
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This structure and implementation is mandatory. If I had the right to choose, I wouldn't have made the Derived class inherited at all, therefore I would have avoided the pointers alltogether. But I can't choose.
So I have two questions:

1. How should I implement memory freeing so that I don't get
   `segmentation fault` and remove all allocated memory correctly?
2. Is it possible to put `Base` class pointers into the `Derived` class vector
   without making copies and without destroying the objects when I
   remove them from the vector? The idea is to have Base class objects, the existence of which doesn't depend on the existence of a `Derived` class object.

I apologise if this question has already been asked. I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

EDIT: I fixed the crash by changing the Derived class boss pointer to something else, different than itself, in the destructor of the derived class.

Comment: To answer your question in the first snippet: Yes. You *must* declare `Base`'s destructor `virtual`.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I edited my question with your suggestion.

Comment: Note: a strange behaviour I noticed is that when the program ends, the destructors of the `Base` and the `Derived` classes are called around 15 times, when in reality, in my main function I only created one `Base` instance and one `Derived` instance, and the vector indeed had only 1 pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `delete this->boss;` in your `Base::~Base()` definition. Assuming `Base` models employees and `Derived` models bosses, this is equivalent to a boss losing their job when any of their employees leave; it doesn't make sense, and if a `Derived` object has employees, a segmentation fault will inevitably occur upon destruction.

I suspect the reason you observe `~Base()` and `~Derived()` being called multiple times per destruction of a `Derived` object is because once `this->boss` is `delete`d, its `employees`/`team` vector is freed, and thus the iterators used in your range-based `for` loop become invalid.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow.